# Inserting empty string on Windows MySQL doesn't use default value

Tags: mysql, windows, insert

Why inserting `''` on a column with default integer value on MYSQL/WINDOWS produces
ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: `''` for column 'id' at row 1

The query is:

```
insert into test2 (id,test) values('','');
```

If I use this query on MYSQL/LINUX, it runs just fine:

```
mysql>  insert into test2 (id,test) values('','');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 2 warnings (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

`id` is autoincrement
`test` column is INT and has default value 0

Thanks.

SOLUTION:
on my windows machine i disable "strict" mode
in my.ini file, i removed STRICT_TRANS_TABLES from sql-mode=

Comment: `''` is not a valid number, it's a string - why would you ever want to insert a string into a number column? The difference in behavior probably comes from using a different value for the `strict_mode` or the `no_auto_value_on_zero` configuration parameter. If you do a `show warnings` on the Linux installation you'll probably see the explanation. In general you should not ignore the message `2 warnings`.

Answer (score 1):

## PROBLEM

You need to insert nothing ?

## SOLUTION

Then, insert nothing at all ... literally !!!

One of the following will work

```
INSERT INTO test2 () VALUES (),(),();
INSERT INTO test2 (test) VALUES (NULL),(NULL),(NULL);
INSERT INTO test2 (id) VALUES (NULL),(NULL),(NULL);
```

## SAMPLE DATA

```
use test
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test2;
CREATE TABLE test2
(id int not null auto_increment primary key,
test int not null default 0);
SHOW CREATE TABLE test2\G
SELECT * FROM test2;
```

## SAMPLE DATA LOADED

```
mysql> use test
Database changed
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test2;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE test2
    -> (id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    -> test int default 0);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.34 sec)

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE test2\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: test2
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `test2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `test` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM test2;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## QUERIES EXECUTED

If `id` and `test` are the only two columns in the table, the INSERT does not need a column list. If there are other columns in `test2` besides `id` and `test`, name the `test` column and insert a NULL. Keep in mind, inserting a NULL into a column that has `DEFAULT 0` will become `0`.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test2;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test2 () VALUES (),(),();
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO test2 (test) VALUES (NULL),(NULL),(NULL);
Query OK, 3 rows affected, 3 warnings (0.06 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 3

mysql> INSERT INTO test2 (id) VALUES (NULL),(NULL),(NULL);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM test2;
+----+------+
| id | test |
+----+------+
|  1 |    0 |
|  2 |    0 |
|  3 |    0 |
|  4 |    0 |
|  5 |    0 |
|  6 |    0 |
|  7 |    0 |
|  8 |    0 |
|  9 |    0 |
+----+------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

CAVEAT #1 : I did this in Windows 8.1 from the command line

```
mysql> select * from information_schema.global_variables
    -> where variable_name like 'version%';
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| VARIABLE_NAME           | VARIABLE_VALUE               |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| VERSION_COMMENT         | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| VERSION_COMPILE_MACHINE | x86_64                       |
| VERSION_COMPILE_OS      | Win64                        |
| VERSION                 | 5.6.15                       |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.07 sec)

mysql>
```

CAVEAT #2 : I am using MySQL's default SQL mode. Thus, I did not need to disable anything.

Answer (score -2):

loading empty values by a date file will insert the data with empty strings instead of NULL.
I solved my case loading the data into tekst fields and subsequently ran an update:
update table <> set col1=NULL where col1='';

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.